# merging json in jquery-ui

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-plugins

What function does jquery ui use to override the default options passed to a plugin on init?

My plugin has an option that defaults to "false" and if you specify "true" it does something else. And if you specify an object (a json with more jsons nested) you open a whole bunch of possibilities. i want to set defaults for these options i know that ui is doing the same thing for standard "defaults" set, so where can i find that function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was [answered on the jQuery forum](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/merging-json)

It's [jQuery.extend](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)